# Android mustache execute complex map got wrong exception (Java)

Tags: java, android, json, mustache

I got a complex JSON which I'd like to render with mustache, when I do this with ObjC, everything is fine;but when I use template.execute(mapData) in android jmustache,I got a exception says:
No method or field with name "myName" on line 1;

here is my JSON:

```
{
    "A" : {
        "Aa" : {
          "Aa1" : "Aa1"
        },
        "Ab" : "Ab"
      },
      "B" : "b",
      "C" : false,
      "D" : [
        {
          "Da" : "Da",
          "Db" : 0
        }
      ]
    }
```

I notice there is a "map.containsKey(name)" in "BaseCollector.java" return false when name is "Aa","Aa1"... but return true when name is "A","B","C","D".
Is there any way I can solve this without change the jmustache?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I got it wrong.
My mustache only contains objects in "A",but I use the whole Map,that causes the exception.
If someone got the same problem, you might want to check your JSON and Mustache matchs each other.
BTW, if some key in mustache doesn't exists in JSON, ObjC would render the mustache properly,but Android doesn't, so you'd better do it like:

```
{{#A}}{{A}}{{/A}}
```

not just

```
{{A}}
```